# Print_R of class as array

Tags: php, arrayaccess, debug-print

I have a class, that actually operates over a complicated array to make the manipulation more simple. The format of original array looks like this:

```
array(
    array(
        "name" =>"foo",
        "type" =>8,         //The array is NBT format and 8 stands for string
        "value" =>"somevalue"
    )
}
```

The class takes array like above as constructor:

```
class NBT_traverser implements ArrayAccess {
    function __construct(&$array) {
       $this->array = $array;
    }
}
```

Then, this is how the members are accessed:

```
$parser = new NBT_traverser($somearray);   
echo $parser["foo"];  //"somevalue"
```

When I `print_R` the class, I get the list of its values and the original complicated array. Like this:

```
 object(NBT_traverser)#2 (1) { 
    ["nbt":"NBT_traverser":private]=> &array(1) {
 /*Tons of ugly array contents*/
 }
```

Instead, I'd like to get this like the output of `print_r`:

```
array(
    "foo" => "somevalue"
)
```

Is it possible to trick the `print_r` to do this? Current behavior makes it harder to debug with the class, than without it.
Of course, I **can** write my own method to print it, but I want to make the usage more simple for the users of the class. Instead, I wanted to give `print_R` something, that It will print as array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have issues if you are extending `ArrayAccess` just write a method to get your values

Example

```
$random = range("A", "F");
$array = array_combine($random, $random);

$parser = new NBT_traverser($array);
echo $parser->getPrint();
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [A] => A
    [B] => B
    [C] => C
    [D] => D
    [E] => E
    [F] => F
)
```

Class Used

```
class NBT_traverser implements ArrayAccess {
    private $used; // you don't want this
    protected $ugly = array(); // you don't want this
    public $error = 0202; // you don't want this
    private $array = array(); // you want this
    function __construct(&$array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    function getPrint() {
        return print_r($this->array, true);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->array[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->array[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->array[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->array[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->array[$offset]) ? $this->array[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I can write my own printing method, I think thisis clear. What I wanted was overiding `print_r` behavior. But I'll give you +1 for nice answer, though useless for me.

Comment: you don't need to override `print_r` just use clean universal format like `json` .. with `ArrayAccess` you are in full control ...

Comment: *" just use clean universal format like"* - I'm writing a parser. It is not my decision, what the format looks like.

Comment: there is no way i would know that  .... but you are still achieve same format with json ... encode and decode forcing it to be array .... I don't have a clear picture of what you want to achieve but best of luck

Comment: It was very easy to write a function to convert messy array into readable one. I knew how to do that - but it was not my question. I needed to know, how to automatically print that nice array - so far, I have to do `print_R($class->nice_array())`.

Comment: I still prefer `var_dump` for more detail information or `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` for simple data structure to `print_r` ... anyway best of luck

Comment: Once the array is converted, it may be passed to `var_dump` as well. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the __toString function in your class

```
class Test
{
    private $_array = array();

    public function __toString()
    {
        return print_r($this->_array, true);
    }
}
```

And then just echo out your class

```
$test = new Test();
echo $test;
```

I think this would print out your array as you want it to be?

```
Array
(
)
```